# Limit $ \sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2 \cdots}}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations, nested-radicals

> Find the limit of the sequence $$\left\{\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2\sqrt{2}}, \sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}}}, \dots\right\}$$

Another way to write this sequence is $$\left\{2^{\frac{1}{2}},\hspace{5 pt} 2^{\frac{1}{2}}2^{\frac{1}{4}},\hspace{5 pt}  2^{\frac{1}{2}}2^{\frac{1}{4}}2^{\frac{1}{8}},\hspace{5 pt}  \dots,\hspace{5 pt}2^{\frac{1}{2^{n+1} - 2}}\right\}$$

So basically we have to find $\lim_{n\to\infty}2^{\frac{1}{2^{n+1} - 2}}$. This equates to $$\lim_{n\to\infty}2^{\frac{1}{2^{\infty+1} - 2}} \Longrightarrow 2^{\frac{1}{2^{\infty}}} \Longrightarrow 1$$

Is this correct? P.S. Finding that $S(n)$ was a pain!

Comment: Your sequence's general term, as you wrote it, is $$2^{\frac12+\frac14+\ldots+\frac1{2^n}}\implies$$you're looking for the limit $$2^{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2^n}}=2^1=2$$

Comment: @DonAntonio Then why is the square root over all other roots? Why isn't it just shown as $(\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{2})....$

Comment: Because $\;\sqrt2\sqrt2\sqrt2\ldots=(\sqrt2)^n\;$ , something *very* different from what you have. What you have is an iterated square root.

Comment: The general term is $2^{1-2^{-n}}$, not $2^{\frac{1}{2^{n+1} - 2}}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hints:

$$x=\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt2\ldots}}\implies x=\sqrt{2x}\implies x^2=2x\implies\ldots$$

Comment: But $1$ isn't a solution.

Comment: No, of course it isn't...and it isn't the sequence's limit, either.

Comment: It is, though..

Comment: Well, if you insist it is, then...what to do?

Comment: All of the answers so far say it's 1 @DonAntonio.

Comment: Not one single one of them say so, but that is unimportant for my point: do you understand my answer? Do you think it is correct? Then the answer that **must** be deduced is that the limit is $\;2\;$ , never mind whether the other answers or the pope say otherwise...or I, and my answer, are wrong, of course. Just think of this: $\;\sqrt2>1\;$, and then you multiply this *further* by a number grater than one, and then again and...how can the limit be one?!

Comment: but then how is my method incorrect?

Comment: Because it is. Read my comment below your question...

Comment: This works once a limit has been shown to exist. It is not too hard to show that the sequence is increasing, and it is pretty simple to show that the sequence is bounded by $2$. Your answer in comments to the question is far superior.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac 1 2 + \frac 1 4 + \frac 1 8 + \dots  = 1 $$

Comment: I'm not sure how you arrived to this conclusion? Did you solve for the partial fraction?

Comment: @Jossie: Geometric Series with the ratio as $\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: @Jossie just add up the powers of 2, you will get something like this.
$$\frac 1 2 + \frac 1 4 + \dots + \frac 1 {2^n}$$
this is just a geometric sequence with ratio $1/2$. If you take limit $n \to \infty $ you will get it equal to $1$.

Comment: But how is that evident from what I posted? I'm being dense.

Comment: @Jossie
$$\{2^{\frac 1 2},2^{\frac 1 4}2^{\frac 1 8} , \dots , 2^{\frac 1 2}\dots 2^{\frac 1 {2^n}}\} = \{  2^{\frac 1 2} , 2^{\frac 1 2 + \frac 1 4 }, \dots , 2^{\frac 1 2 + \frac1 4 + \dots + \frac 1 {2^n}}\}  $$
and also check [this sum out](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F2+%2B+1%2F4+%2B+...+%2B+1%2F2%5En)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative proof (of sorts):

If the sequence has a limit, then it will be a fixed point of $f(x)=\sqrt{2x}$, and hence a solution to $x=\sqrt{2x}$. The solutions are clearly $x=0, 2$, and you should be able to show that 0 is out because all of the terms in the sequence are $\gt 1$ and hence the limit is $\geq 1$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how you've arrived at the solution being a fixed point of $f(x)$?

Comment: Basically through a rough application of the idea of fixed-point iteration. Broadly speaking, if you have a sequence generated by iteratively applying a function (i.e. x_{n+1} = f(x_n)) and there is sufficient continuity and convergence happening, then the limit of the sequence will be a fixed point of the function.

Comment: I wasn't sure if you were using a piece of deeper theory I missed and from which the result would follow immediately. If I read you correctly, you are using further insight about the behavior of the function and some intuition which are beyond your original post. Thanks!

Comment: I am, but if you look up fixed-point iteration and fixed point theorems it should give you the missing pieces.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: take a logarithm of every element in your sequence.